# Probability over different time spans

Tags: probability

I have  aquestion: 
Which is more likely to happen: flipping a coin 10 times in a 10 minute period and getting heads each time OR flipping a coin 10 times but over a period of 10 years and getting heads each time? The flipping itself takes the same amount of time. But it is the interval between flips that differed between scenarios.
I am not in math. I have  some knowledge of bio-statistics. Thank you!

Comment: It is a question in itself what sort of intuition led you to ask this question in the first place. Do you think (maybe subconsciously) that previous results of flipping the coin somehow influence the subsequent results? (And therefore, as we know, the "influence" fades over time, so you would expect the influence to maybe persist for 10 minutes, but not for 10 years...) Or is it some other subconscious process? Whatever it is, it is misleading and not useful for you - whatever science you are engaged in.

Answer (score 1):

They are equally likely, because part of the mathematical definition of "fair coin" is that it has no memory of how it came up the last time it was flipped. A similar question in bio-statistics (which you know) may well have a very different answer. Biological systems age.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the coin is unaffected by the passage of time, both
events have probability $2^{-10} \approx 0.001$.

The above also assumes that the coin is fair: the probability of heads is the same as that of tails. If the probability of flipping heads was instead $p$, we would have $p^{10}$ for both events instead.

Answer (score 0):

The time is not important to determine the probability of this kind of events, thus the two events are equally likely.